# UIView performance issue if function is called after view is shown

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uibutton

I have a `UIView` that appears on the click of a `UIButton`. The thing is that this `view` is for `scraping` a website, so before revealing the actual view, I have a `coverView` with a `loadingAnimation` that is shown until the data is scraped from the website:

```
@objc func addWishButtonTapped() {
    self.coverView.isHidden = false
    self.loadingAnimation.play()
    self.wishView.isHidden = false
    self.cancelButton.isHidden = false
    self.wishView.dropDownButton.dropView.dropOptions = dropOptions
    crawlWebsite {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.hideLoadingView()
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that when calling `crawlWebsite` like above, the animation is clunky and does not look smooth:

[clunky animation](https://gofile.io/d/dZcu9B)

I found out when I don't call `crawlWebsite` it is looking perfectly smooth:

[smooth animation](https://gofile.io/d/CqwMNM)

This is `crawlWebsite`:

```
func crawlWebsite(finished: @escaping () -> Void){
    
    var html: String?
    let url = webView.url
    html = (self.getHTMLfromURL(url: url))
    print(url as Any)
    let directoryURL = url! as NSURL
    let urlString: String = directoryURL.absoluteString!
    // save url to wish
    self.wishView.link = urlString
    OpenGraphDataDownloader.shared.fetchOGData(urlString: urlString) { result in
        switch result {
        case let .success(data, _):
            // get productTitle
            guard let title = data.pageTitle else {finished(); return}
            print(title)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.wishView.wishNameTextField.text = title
                self.wishView.enableButton()
            }
            // get productImage
            guard let imageURL = data.imageUrl else {finished(); return }
            UIImage.loadFrom(url: imageURL, completion: { (image) in
                
                guard let image = image else { return }
                self.wishView.wishImageView.image = image
                self.imagesArray.append(image)
                self.wishView.hideAddImageButton()
                self.wishView.showImageView()
                finished()
            })
            finished()
            
        case let .failure(error, _):
            finished()
            print("OpenGraph-error: " + error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.getContentFromHTML(html: html)
    }
}
```

Im quite stuck here and don't know what is going one here. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Try to call `crawlWebsite` in a background thread.

Comment: What is self.getContentFromHTML(html: html) doing? Also I'd probably move every view update inside the completion handler and only access the main thread there.

Comment: @krlbsk how do I do that?

Comment: @Chris Try `DispatchQueue.global().async { self.crawlWebsite { ... } }`.

Comment: @MarcoBoerner it is searching the HTML for price and images

Comment: @krlbsk `UI API called from background thread: WKWebView.url must be used from main thread only` & `UIView.isHidden must be used from main thread only`

Comment: @Chris So wrap them in a main thread using `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

Comment: @krlbsk thanks, that is working!